# Issues with running a php script through cPanel Cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am very frustrated now. I have a php script sync.php in the following absolute path folder.

```
home2/**username**/public_html/**mystore.net**/wp-content/plugins/pets/admin/sync.php
```

On running the `sync.php` file manually, it works perfectly. So the php script is not the problem.

My cron command reads `php -q /home2/**username**/public_html/pets/admin/sync.php`

This is a hostgator server if this helps.
The email returns - **No input file specified.**

I would really appreciate anyone helping me out with this.

Cheers,
RakeshD

Comment: `-q` flag is for CGI only. Try running `php -f /home2/**username**/public_html/pets/admin/sync.php` to parse and execute the file instead. IF you want it to run in "quiet" mode, prepend `>> /dev/null` to stop any output (essentially writing the output to nothing)

Comment: Doesnt work. Same output.

Comment: Can you try `curl` or `wget` as your cron command? `wget http://my-domain.com/pets/admin/sync.php`